# comparing arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, compare, equals

```
int [] nir1 = new int [2];
nir1[1] = 1;
nir1[0] = 0;


int [] nir2 = new int [2];
nir2[1] = 1;
nir2[0] = 0;

boolean t = nir1.equals(nir2);
boolean m = nir1.toString().equals(nir2.toString());
```

Why are both m and t false? What is the correct way to compare 2 arrays in Java?

Comment: `char[].equals` is doing a memory comparison, not a contents comparison

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [Arrays.equals](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28int%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29) method. Example:

```
boolean b = Arrays.equals(nir1, nir2); //prints true in this case
```

Comment: Hi @CoolBeans, I have Set<Integer[]> with some duplicate arrays in it. How can i make this set of integers unique?

Answer (score 10):

The reason `t` returns false is because arrays use the methods available to an `Object`. Since this is using `Object#equals()`, it returns false because `nir1` and `nir2` are not the same object.

In the case of `m`, the same idea holds. `Object#toString()` prints out an object identifier. In my case when I printed them out and checked them, the result was

```
nir1 = [I@3e25a5
nir2 = [I@19821f
```

Which are, of course, not the same.

CoolBeans is correct; use the static `Arrays.equals()` method to compare them.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Arrays.equals` instead of `array1.equals(array2)`. `Arrays.equals(array1, array2)` will check the content of the two arrays and the later will check the reference. `array1.equals(array2)` simply means `array1 == array2` which is not true in this case.

```
public static boolean perm (String s, String t){

   if (s.length() != t.length()) {

         return false;

   }
   char[] perm1 = s.toCharArray();

   Arrays.sort(perm1);

   char[] perm2 = t.toCharArray();

   Arrays.sort(perm2);

   return Arrays.equals(perm1, perm2);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
boolean t = Arrays.equals(nir1,nir2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to point out the reason this is failing:

arrays are not Objects, they are primitive types.

When you print nir1.toString(), you get a java identifier of nir1 in textual form. Since nir1 and nir2 were allocated seperately, they are unique and this will produce different values for toString().

The two arrays are also not equal for the same reason. They are separate variables, even if they have the same content.

Like suggested by other posters, the way to go is by using the Arrays class:

```
Arrays.toString(nir1);
```

and

```
Arrays.deepToString(nir1);
```

for complex arrays.

Also, for equality:

```
Arrays.equals(nir1,nir2);
```

Comment: Arrays actually are objects; see the JLS here. http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/arrays.doc.html

Comment: That's so strange. If they are objects, then why can't I extend them or change their behavior? If that would be possible, the OP could override toString(),equals() and hashCode() and his method would work.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this:**

```
return Arrays.equals(perm1, perm2)
```

**Instead of this:**

```
return perm1.equals(perm2);
```

Please have to look [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_equals_char.htm)