# arr1 == arr2 is false why?

Tags: java, arrays

The following:

```
class ArrayCompare 
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        int []arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        int []arr2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        System.out.println("arr1 == arr2 is " + (arr1 == arr2));
    }
}
```

Returns `arr1 == arr2 is false`

Why is this? Why is `arr1 Equals to arr2` is `false`.

Should this not be true?

Comment: The contents of the arrays are equal. But each one is a reference to a different object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [comparing arrays in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588460/comparing-arrays-in-java)

Comment: Off-site resource that has nice pictures that can really help to visualize this: http://www.javaranch.com/campfire/StoryPassBy.jsp

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No it should not be true. You are comparing the references of two distinct objects, so `==` should return false.

Use `Arrays.equals(arr1,arr2)` if you wish to compare the contents of the two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

**Java eye is not human eye.**

Though the content is same, since both references  are pointing to difference Objects , `==` returns false.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.equals(arr1, arr2)); // prints true
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare references of two different objects using `==` so therefore it returns false. To compare the contents use:

```
 Arrays.equals(arr1, arr2);
```

Also, might be worth reading the following [Java == vs .equals() confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion)

Answer (score 0):

`arr1.equals(arr2)` is the same as `arr1 == arr2`, i.e. is it the same array, i.e. whether the references (pointers) are same.
Use:

```
Arrays.equals(arr1, arr2);
```

to compare the contents of the arrays. This will return true if the two specified arrays of ints are equal to one another.
So, use:

```
System.out.println("arr1 == arr2 is " + Arrays.equals(arr1, arr2));
```