# Make program check if password is correct

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextfield

I am writing a program for school and I want it to check if the password entered is correct but the program continues to run even if the password is incorrect. Below is my entire program!

```
    public class ma_RocketProgram
{

  static Console c;


//***********************************Main Program******************************

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {

    c = new Console (35, 85);

    c.setColor (Color.black);
    c.fillRect (0, 0, 700, 550);

    Image picture1 = loadImage ("USA.png");      
    c.drawImage (picture1, 200, 100, null);

    IntroMessage();

    c.getChar();

    Password();

    c.setColor (Color.blue);

    c.drawRect (175, 475, 300, 10);

    for (int a = 176; a <= 465; a++)
    {

      c.setColor (Color.green);

      c.fillRect(a, 476, 10, 9);

      try
      {

        Thread.sleep(25);

      }

      catch (InterruptedException ex) 
      { 

        Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

      }

    }

  }

//********************************Image Loader Method**************************

  public static Image loadImage (String name)
  {
    Image img = null;

    try
    {

      img = ImageIO.read (new File (name));

    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {

    }

    return img;

  }

//******************************Intro Message*************************************

  public static void IntroMessage()

  {

    Font f = new Font ("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 30);

    c.setColor (Color.green);
    c.setFont (f);

    c.drawString ("W", 60, 25);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString (" e", 60, 25);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString ("  l", 60, 25);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString ("   c", 60, 25);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString ("    o", 60, 25);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString ("     m", 60, 25);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString ("      e", 60, 25);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString ("        t", 60, 25);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString ("         o", 60, 25);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString ("           t", 60, 25);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString ("            h", 60, 25);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString ("             e", 60, 25);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString ("               R", 60, 25);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString ("                o", 60, 25);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString ("                 c", 60, 25);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString ("                  k", 60, 25);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString ("                   e", 60, 25);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString ("                    t", 60, 25);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString ("                      L", 60, 25);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString ("                       a", 60, 25);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString ("                        u", 60, 25);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString ("                         n", 60, 25);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString ("                          c", 60, 25);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString ("                           h", 60, 25);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString ("                            e", 60, 25);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString ("                             r", 60, 25);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString ("P", 250, 60);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString (" r", 250, 60);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString ("  o", 250, 60);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString ("   g", 250, 60);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString ("    r", 250, 60);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString ("     a", 250, 60);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.drawString ("      m", 250, 60);

    try
    {

      Thread.sleep(50);

    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex) 
    { 

      Thread.currentThread ().interrupt (); 

    }

    c.setColor(Color.white);

    c.drawRect(215, 360, 215, 55);

    Font f2 = new Font ("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 15);

    c.setColor (Color.green);
    c.setFont (f2);

    c.drawString ("Press any key to", 245, 375);
    c.drawString ("display password field", 225, 400);

  }

//************************************Password*************************

  public static void Password()
  {

    JPanel panel = new JPanel ();

    JLabel label = new JLabel ("Enter the password");

    JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField(10);

    panel.add (label);
    panel.add (pass);

    String[] options = new String[]{"Enter", "Cancel"};

    int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog (null, panel, "Rocket Launcher", JOptionPane.NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, options[1]);

    if (option == 0)
    {

      char[] password = pass.getPassword();

      char[] passw = new char[]{'1'};

      boolean b = Arrays.equals(password, passw);

      if (b = false)
      {

        System.exit(0);

      }

    }

  }


}
```

Comment: Maybe try `Arrays.equals(password, passw)`

Comment: Possible duplicate to [comparing arrays in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588460/comparing-arrays-in-java)

Comment: I tried that method but no luck. I have the password method in a separate bigger program and if the password is wrong, it does not exit.

Comment: You are *assigning* `false` to `b`. That's one reason not to use comparison with booleans; just say `if (!b)`.

Answer (score 2):

A quick test shows that...

```
char[] password = new char[]{'u', 'n', 'k', 'w', 'o', 'n'};
char[] passw = new char[]{'u', 'n', 'k', 'w', 'o', 'n'};

if (Arrays.equals(password, passw)) {
    System.out.println("Are equal");
} else {
    System.out.println("Are not equal");
}
```

prints `Are equal` and

```
char[] password = new char[]{'u', 'n', 'k', 'w', 'o', 'n'};
char[] passw = new char[]{'U', 'n', 'k', 'w', 'o', 'n'};

if (Arrays.equals(password, passw)) {
    System.out.println("Are equal");
} else {
    System.out.println("Are not equal");
}
```

prints `Are not equal`

This proves, in concept, that `Arrays.equals` works

A quick glance at the [`JOptionPane` JavaDocs for `showOptionDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-int-javax.swing.Icon-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-) highlights

> Returns:
>   an integer indicating the option chosen by the user, or CLOSED_OPTION if the user closed the dialog

While a little obscure, this means that, in your case, it will return `0` if the user selects <kbd>Enter</kbd> or `1` of the user selects <kbd>Cancel</kbd>

So, based on that, you code will only work if the user selects <kbd>Cancel</kbd>

This is where `System.out.println(...)` is really useful to print out the actual values of variables

So your should actually look something more like...

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter the password");
JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField(10);

panel.add(label);
panel.add(pass);

String[] options = new String[]{"Enter", "Cancel"};

int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, "Rocket Launcher", JOptionPane.NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, options[1]);

if (option == 0) {
    char[] password = pass.getPassword();
    char[] passw = new char[]{'u', 'n', 'k', 'w', 'o', 'n'};

    if (Arrays.equals(password, passw)) {
        System.out.print("Right");
    } else {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```