# skipping a condition scope in java

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a program with 2 classes - a Node class and a Problem class.

The Problem class has an PriorityQueue  attribute.

The Node class has an char [] state attribute.

I'm trying to run a function at the Problem class with the next input:
(Node node , PriorityQueue  q) and check if there is any node in q with the same state as the node. state

```
public boolean insideQueue (Node node, PriorityQueue<Node> q){
        for (Node ele : q) {
            if(ele.state == node.state) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I tried to use toString() method to solve the problem, and Im having a problem to understand how I can solve this problem with another way (maybe because I'm using python 95% of my time)

I'm adding a photo from my debugger.

[image: both values should be equal]

Thank you very much

Comment: `==` compares the addresses of Objects. As you can see from your debugger, 840 != 835. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588460/comparing-arrays-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Java `==` compares the object references for you, which are `char[7]@840` and `char[7]@835`, so they are different.
Converting to `String`, and comparing the result as `a.equals(b)` could work (`==` would not), but there are pre-defined methods for comparing arrays in the `Arrays` class, [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(char[],%20char[])](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(char%5B%5D,%20char%5B%5D)) is the one you could use in particular, so

> ```
> if(ele.state == node.state) {
> ```

becomes

```
if(Arrays.equals(ele.state, node.state)) {
```

Comment: Converting to `String` ***c**ould* work, depending on how you do the conversion, e.g. `ele.state.toString()` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have absolutely no idea what you mean by

> skipping a condition scope in java

However, the code you wrote makes no sense, so presumably the problem with it is what you're struggling with.

A `char[]` is a java array; an object (all things in java are objects, except primitives, which are a hardcoded list of 8 types: int, double, boolean - the lowercased stuff. char is a primitive, but arrays of primitives are objects).

All expressions that resolve to an object type are **references** - they are like an entry in a phone book, and not the phone itself. Merely instructions on how to get there.

`==` in java compares the raw value. For primitives, that just compares values, but for references (and, remember, all expressions of non-primitive types *are* references), it **compares references**, i.e. it doesn't check if it's the same phone number, it checks if it's the same entry in the same phone book.

You can therefore have 2 different objects whose contents are identical; with `==`, that would return **false**, because `==` checks if they are the same object reference, not if the content inside them is equal.

For that you ordinarily want `.equals`, but arrays in java are low-level primitive things designed for speed and for access to low-level hardware, and not for actual normal use. I have no idea why you don't just have strings here. At any rate, for normal objects, you just call `.equals()` on it. For arrays, no such luck, their equals method also is a check for same object identity (for somewhat solid reasons). To compare **content**, you need `Arrays.equals`.

So:

```
if (Arrays.equals(ele.state, node.state)) { ... }
```

will return `true` even if `ele.state` and `node.state` are pointing at different char arrays, but those char arrays have the exact same content. Which, according to your debugger paste, they do.

Alternatively, don't use arrays unless you really know what you are doing. Those should be strings. Then all you really need is `ele.state.equals(node.state)`.